# Order random form options with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I have some randomly generated form options I need to reorder, in a defined order.

Example:

```
<select id="the_size">
   <option value="">Select something</option>
   <option value="xl">XL</option>
   <option value="l">L</option>
   <option value="s">S</option>
</select>
```

Should be:

```
<option value="s">S</option>
<option value="l">L</option>
<option value="xl">XL</option>
```

And again:

```
<select id="the_size">
   <option value="">Select something</option>
   <option value="s">S</option>
   <option value="m">M</option>
   <option value="xs">XS</option>
</select>
```

Should be: xs, s, m.

How can I achieve this? Maybe hide everything, define an array (xs, s, m, l, xl, xxl..), loop a conditional statement and write every correspondent value if it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort the options and then (re)append them to the `select` element:

```
var c = ['xs', 's', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl'],
    s = document.querySelector('#the_size'), 
    o = [].slice.call(s.options);

o.sort(function(a, b) {
  return c.indexOf(a.value) - c.indexOf(b.value);
}).forEach(function(el) {
   s.appendChild(el);
});
```